# Form values are not available in ActionForm after submit using jquery in IE11 windows 10

Tags: jquery, html, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a form with table. This table will have multiple rows. First time this table will be loaded with one row, we have a button called "Add row" to add new row for this table.

There are three columns in each row. at the bottom of the page we have a save button. when i click the save button to submit the form after creating a new row with values. its working fine in IE mode 5. but when I try with IE11 its not save the data of the new row which we added. so after save action newly added row is not came in view.

Issue:

when I submit the form with values after adding row. it navigates to action class the "ActionForm" parameter has get the values which we have submitted. when I test the ActionForm parameter which is got form the form didn't have the values of new row which I added.

I tried in the UI side by using `$("form").serialize()` to get the form values before submit in client side. but I didn't find the new row values in that `$("form").serialize()` out put in console. but this same thing is working fine in IE5 mode.

DoM in IE11 browser - IE5 mode:

```
<form name="empform" action="/emp/savedata.do" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post"/>
 <table width="98%" align="center" id="mainTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
     <tr class="header" id="row"> 
        <td> empname</td
        <td>empdesc</td
       <td>JoinDate</td
     </tr>
   <tr class="multiparty" id="r0" style="display:none visibility:hidden"> 
    <td> <textarea name="empname"></textarea></td
    <td> <textarea name="empdesc"></textarea></td
   <td> <input name="joindate" type="text">/></td
 </tr>   
     <tr class="multiparty" id="row0"> 
        <td> <textarea name="empname"> Test</textarea></td
        <td> <textarea name="empdesc"> Test</textarea></td
       <td> <input name="joindate" type="text"> 21/01/2017 /></td
     </tr>
     <tr class="multiparty" id="row1"> 
        <td> <textarea name="empname"> Test</textarea></td
        <td> <textarea name="empdesc"> Test</textarea></td
       <td> <input name="joindate" type="text"> 21/01/2017 /></td
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></form>
```

Add row

```
<input name="addrow" id="addrow" click="duplicateHiddenrow('mainTable') type="button" value="AddRow" />
```

DOM in IE11 Windows 10 IE11 mode

```
     <form name="empform" action="/emp/savedata.do" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post"/>

         <input name="isEditable" type="hidden" value="true">
       </form>
         <table width="98%" align="center" id="mainTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

   <tbody>
            <tr class="header" id="row"> 
                    <td> empname</td
                    <td>empdesc</td
                   <td>JoinDate</td
                 </tr>


          <tr class="multiparty" id="r0" style="display:none visibility:hidden"> 
                <td> <textarea name="empname"></textarea></td
                <td> <textarea name="empdesc"></textarea></td
               <td> <input name="joindate" type="text">/></td
             </tr> 

            <tr class="multiparty" id="row0"> 
                    <td> <textarea name="empname"> Test</textarea></td
                    <td> <textarea name="empdesc"> Test</textarea></td
                   <td> <input name="joindate" type="text"> 21/01/2017 /></td
                 </tr>

             <tr class="multiparty" id="row1"> 
                    <td> <textarea name="empname"> Test</textarea></td
                    <td> <textarea name="empdesc"> Test</textarea></td
                   <td> <input name="joindate" type="text"> 21/01/2017 /></td
                 </tr>
                  </tbody>

                </table>

            </form>
```

Add row

```
<input name="addrow" id="addrow" click="duplicateHiddenrow('mainTable') type="button" value="AddRow" />
```

JQuery

```
function saveForm() {

   $('form').eq(0).attr('action','saveProperty.do');
   $('form').eq(0).submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to show add row button code also. and your form posting code also.Because current jQuery code is doing nothing

Comment: I have added the code of Addrow .@AlivetoDie